# Borders of two divs don't meet when the content of div has margin

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML and CSS code.

```css
#foo {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#bar {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
<p>
Foo
</p>
<p>
Foo
</p>
</div>
<div id="bar">
<p>
Bar
</p>
<p>
Bar
</p>
</div>
```

I want to know how to get rid of the gap between the red box and blue box. I know that the gap between them exists because of the margin due to the paragraph element in the lower div. I want to learn how to make an elegant fix that gets rid of this gap.

Comment: It's a perfect example of [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing), and there are many ways to prevent that, such as using overflow, float, flexbox etc.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the margin on the paragraph tags and switch it to padding, or add padding to your divs and get rid of the `p` tag altogether. Assuming your `p` tag has top and bottom margin of 16px, an alternative could look like this:

```
#foo {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#foo p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px 0;
}
#bar {
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-top: 0;
}
#bar p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px 0;
}
```

Comment: I am going to need the margin for paragraph tags because in my real application, I have multiple paragraphs in each div.

Comment: That's fine. The padding will work the same way as the margin and give you spacing between paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution. You can just add `overflow: hidden;` to second div.

```css
#foo {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#bar {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
<p>
Foo
</p>
<p>
Foo
</p>
</div>
<div id="bar">
<p>
Bar
</p>
<p>
Bar
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#foo {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#bar {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-top: 0;
}

.foobar p { 
  margin: 0 0 0.5em; 
  padding: 0.25em; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.foobar p:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="foobar">
<p>
Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores.
</p>
<p>
Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores.
</p>
</div>
<div id="bar" class="foobar">
<p>
Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores.
</p>
<p>
Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores.
</p>
</div>
```